# Understanding Dlib Kernel implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, machine-learning, dlib

I'm starting using dlib, and I have hard time understanding the way kernels are implemented. I started with the k-kmeans algorithm as I know this clustering method. However I cannot figure out where the kernel is computed. The input data are a matrix (not a kernel) and the algorithm never transform the data into a kernel.
I would expect a kernel class returning a square matrix. But I have not seen anything like this!
I want to use dlib to implement a clustering algorithm using kernels and dlib sounds a good solution to do so. Does anyone has a documentation on how it is implemented or can explain me how it does work?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A kernel is basically just a function that takes two input samples and outputs a single number.  So yes, sometimes you will see code that then computes an N by N matrix of all the possible kernel function outputs for N samples.  However, this is a somewhat naive implementation strategy since it requires O(N^2) RAM.  So most real world kernel method software uses some kind of delayed evaluation or caching strategy to avoid this problem.

In the kernel K-means implementation in dlib this is done with the the [kcentroid](http://dlib.net/ml.html#kcentroid) object.  Inside the kcentroid you can see that it's invoking the kernel function in a number of places and doing all the "kernel stuff".  You can read over the documentation for the kcentroid to understand what it does.  Although, if you are just getting started with kernel methods then you will really need to get a book on the subject. I highly recommend picking one of these:

- Learning with Kernels: Support Vector Machines, Regularization, Optimization, and Beyond by Bernhard Schlkopf and Alexander J. Smola
- Kernel Methods for Pattern Analysis by John Shawe-Taylor and Nello Cristianini

Answer (score 0):

For a set of N data points, the kernel is usually specified by an NxN matrix whose (i,j)th entry gives the value of the kernel between data point i and data point j. This works for kernel methods as long as the matrix is symmetric and positive definite, which is guaranteed to be true for a true kernel.

Comment: allright, if I do understand what you say, in the example provided the k-kmeans is not used as kernel but it would work just the same if a kernel was provided ? So how could I get a kernel from the inputed data ?